# Ant - replace/encode Strings

Tags: java, ant

I want an Ant Task to build my Java-Project and obfuscate that with ProGuard.

I need a solution to encode hardcoded Strings like

```
 System.out.println("Hello");
 String test = "Whats up";
 System.out.println("Answer: " + test);
```

ProGuard doesn't support any solution for Strings. My idea is to replace it automatically before obfuscating.

Can I use Javassist for that? I have two solution-ideas:

**1**: After the JAR is created, i override Strings with Javasisst and add an Method like

```
 System.out.println(StringEncode.decode(1234));
 String test = StringEncode.decode(633524236);
 System.out.println(StringEncode.decode(88302) + test);
```

**2**: Before the JAR is created im copy the source files and replace that over RegExpr.

I need a quick start guide for a best practice.

The Method **StringEncode.decode(88302)** is an example. This static method will encode integer values with an algorhytm to the original String. The same algorhytm will be used for encoding.

I hope you can give me an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

I have write a own Ant Task for that.

```
 <taskdef resource="task.properties" classpath="libs/ObfuscateStrings.jar" />
 <obfuscatestrings dir="temp/" />
```